# How to connect IoT device to IBM Watson IoT Platform using MQTT server

Tags: mqtt, iot, watson-iot

I have an IoT device that is set up and running via MQTT server with following parameters: hostname, port, clientId, username, password etc.

How am I supposed to connect such device with Watson IoT platform when there is no field for such parameters? During device registration process at Watson IoT Platform, I could not find any of these parameters.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

See the following information from the Watson IoT platform documentation [here](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/IoT/reference/security/connect_devices_apps_gw.html#connect_devices_apps_gw)

Key Info:

---

When you register a Device with the Watson IoT platform, the `Device Type` , `Device Id`, and Device `Authentication Token` are then used to connect the device via MQTT:

- `hostname` will be `<your-org-id>.messaging.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com`
- port can be `8883` or `433` for Secure (TLS), or `443` for Non-secure (if your Watson IoT settings allow for `TLS Optional` connections
- `clientId` for devices is of the form `d:orgId:deviceType:deviceId`
- `username` is `use-token-auth`
- `password` is the Device `Authentication Token` chosen (or generated) when the device was registered in the Watson IoT Platform

---

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the device registration process you have been provided with below information:

Organization ID: xxxxxx (has six chars)

Device Type: xxxxxxxxxxx (value of your choice)

Device ID:xxxxxxxxxxxx (value of your choice)

Username: use-token-auth

Token: xxxxxxxxxxxx (value of your choice or automatically generated)

When you connect, you need to provide the hostname, which as per:

https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/IoT/reference/security/connect_devices_apps_gw.html#connect_devices_apps_gw

is: orgId.messaging.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com

so, with the Organization ID provided at the end of device registration this would become: xxxxxx.messaging.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com

If you want to connect as device, the clientID will have the format: d:orgId:deviceType:deviceId

The orgId, deviceType, deviceId are provided at the end of registration process and deviceType, deviceId are created based on your choice.

For Password you need to use the Token, as well provided at the end of device registration process.

The Port, by default is 8883 as the connection is secure and done over TLS. If you want to connect insecurely (and we don't recommend) you can change the settings from IoT Platform dashboard, Security > Connection security. If the latter, you need to use port 1883 for connection.

Answer (score 0):

Documentation for connecting devices can be found below:-

https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/IoT/reference/security/connect_devices_apps_gw.html#connect_devices_apps_gw

https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/IoT/iotplatform_task.html#iotplatform_task

hostname is the messaging url in the form of  'orgId.messaging.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com' where orgId is the name of your organisation.

There are a number of ports you can use but TLS is configured by default so you need to connect your device using TLS with port 8883. You can configure TLS to be optional but this is not recommended.

The clientId for a device is of the form 'd:orgId:deviceType:deviceId' where deviceType and deviceId are the values you specified when you registered your device.

The username is 'use-token-auth' and the password is the one you specified during device registration. If you did not specify a password an auto generated one will have been given to you when you registered the device.